# can spider get item after all pipelines pass?

Tags: python, scrapy

My Process is.

1. spider item go to pipelines ( multiple pipelines )
2. item must be changed because of pipelines (maybe translation, Imagepipelines)..
3. spider get the changed item and Based on item, request another.

[image]

My Problem is.

1. `return item`(in spider) is not make sense and function is done.
2. `yield item` pass item after first pipeline done.

I want to get item ALL Passed pipelines..

Comment: sorry I didn't understand your question correctly. So when you call `return` behaves differently that when you call `yield`? Is this inside the spider or a pipeline?

All items should pass for all pipelines, except when you call the `DropItem` exception

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: In Image,  for example, item['translate'] is emtpy first but after passing pipelines, some data in item['translate']

Comment: Some tasks after it seems like when imagepipeline in piplines, spider get processing item before imagepipeline. I want all processing item include imagepipeline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `item_scraped` signal to let a spider know when an item has passed all the item pipelines.

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#item-scraped